# How can I get all orderlist by group of created date with node sequlize orm?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, nodes

I want to make an API to get group objects of array by created date (like 10 order placed today, 5 order yesterday). Can anyone help me how can I do that?

```
async getdailyList(req, res, next) {
       
        try {
            await db.Order.findAll({
                order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
                include: [{ model: db.customerModel }, { model: db.orderCart, include: [{ 
                model: db.varientModel }] }],
            }).then(list => {
               

                res.status(200).json({ 'success': true, order: list });
            })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    next(err)
                });
        }
        catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ 'errors': "" + err });
        }
    },
```